# How to flag an answer as not answering the question

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

I flagged an [answer to one of my questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/61302/4178) as not answering the question asked. It got declined for lack of evidence. I flagged again stating specifically that it would be better as a comment because, while helpful, still didn't answer the question. It got declined because I mentioned a USB drive, so apparently that's what I was asking, even though I specifically tagged the question as file Sharing and also talked more about that in my question than anything. So, I edited my question to remove the fact that I used a USB drive at all, because it wasn't relevant to what I wanted answered, and then flagged again. It was again declined because flagging an answer is not the way to tell people it doesn't answer the question.

> not an answer – Aug 20 at 4:27   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
>
> This doesn't answer the question I asked and would be better as a comment than an answer. – 45 mins ago   declined - The answer seems to be a reasonable response to the question, as worded. If the OP only wants an answer about using File Sharing, don't spend most of the question talking about other data transfer.
>
> Question has been edited to be about file share and not USB drive (though I don't know why it became about USB drives in the first place) and this answer would be best as a comment as it doesn't answer my question. – 30 mins ago   declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Ok, so my problem here is that I read the FAQ and under the section [Deletetion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) it states that an answer that does not fundamentally answer the question is eligible for removal or deletion. And immediately following is the steps to flag a moderator.

If, in my question, I'm not supposed to flag an answer for not fundamentally answering a question, how am I supposed to let a moderator know about it? Pray that I'll be lucky and they see the answer and decide to convert it from answer to comment?

Is the flagging system somehow different here on apple.se than it is on other SE sites?

Comment: What is un-agreeable about this that would warrant a downvote?

Answer (score 4):

You ask "how to flag an answer as not answering the question." How you flag it is exactly how you have done. Your issue is that the moderators reviewed your flags and disagreed with your assessment that the answer needs to be deleted. The solution is not to keep flagging the answer. If you don't find the answer helpful, don't accept it, don't vote for it, and if you're particularly committed to marking it as not useful, vote against it.

You are correct that the maintainers of the site try to delete things that are posted as answers that don't really answer the question that was asked. There is an exception, however, with regard to a situation known as [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The idea is that a user posts a question asking about potential solution X, but really wants to solve problem Y.

Your original post made it clear that your problem was wanting to transfer large files from one Mac to another. File sharing is both a general concept (sharing files from one computer to another) and the name of a particular technological solution in System Preferences to solve that problem.

When you revised your question, you made it clear you are looking for a specific technical answer to the question "Is there an upper limit on the size of files sharable though Apple's File Sharing service." Your original question was more along the lines "I'm having trouble moving large files from one Mac to another, and I've tried USB but that doesn't work for reason A and I tried File Sharing but that doesn't seem to work either."

While we tend to delete non-answers to keep the site in good order, we also tend to avoid deleting answers that attempt to solve the question described in the original post even if they aren't a direct answer to the question as asked.